# Hide Code when exporting Jupyter notebook to HTML

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm looking for a way to hide code cells (inputs) when export my .iipynb file to a HTML. I don't want the code cells to be visible at all (not some button that turn them off/on). The output is for people that have no idea what a programming language is. I tried many things that I found on the internet but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: can you rewrite the document in word, and export that as html?

Comment: use `# @hidden_cell` https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/hide_code.html

Comment: Maybe that helps https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found that : https://pypi.org/project/hide_code/0.2.0/

It's a jupyter extension and it's working like a charm. I use the command prompt to convert the notebook into an html, since the buttons that comes with the extension don't work for me.

Answer (score 102):

as of now (nbconvert version 5.6.0) the easiest solution seems to be to provide the argument `--no-input` when using the CLI interface of nbconvert:

`jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb --no-input`

it works like magic
more info [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html#cli-flags-and-aliases)

Comment: Use also `--no-prompt` to hide the prompts and have all the cells equally vertically aligned

Comment: changed the syntax and it worked for me `jupyter nbconvert --no-input yourNotebook.ipynb`

Comment: This kills all the input code of all cells. What if you only want to kill the input code of some cells but not all? I suspect there must be a Cell Metadata that will do the trick but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 25):

I wrote an article about different ways [how to hide code in Jupyter Notebook](https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-hide-code/). According to my findings, there are several ways in which this can be done.

### 1. Hide all code in `nbconvert`

When exporting notebook with `nbconvert` you need to add `--no-input` in the command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input your-notebook.ipynb
```

### 2. Hide selected cells

You can hide selected cells by adding a tag `hide_code`, like in the animation below:

[image]

The command that hide code only for selected cells:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='{"hide_code"}' my-notebook.ipynb
```

### 3. Export to HTML with Mercury

The [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) is an open-source for sharing notebooks with non-technical users. It can hide code. It can also generate widgets for the notebook that are connected with variables in the code. The notebook export process is controlled with YAML header, below is the example YAML that hides the code:

```yaml
---
title: My notebook
description: My amazing notebook with hidden code
show-code: False
---
```

The example notebook with YAML header:
[image: example notebook with YAML header]

The HTML (website) generated for the notebook with `Mercury`:
[image]

Comment: While using the 2nd option, I was getting an error 

`traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'remove_cell_tags' trait of a TagRemovePreprocessor instance must be a set, but a value of class 'str' (i.e. '{"hide_code"}') was specified.`.

I had to amend it to 

`jupyter nbconvert --to html --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags={\"hide_code\"} my-notebook.ipynb` 

to make it work.

Note that the first single quotes were removed and I had to use the escape backslash before each double quote.

Answer (score 23):

You can do this with an NBConvert template.  Most of the examples out there are for latex/PDF, and won't work with HTML, which uses a different set of templates (and, for some reason, a different extension and slightly different file syntax).

Write the following into a template file called `hidecode.tpl`:

```
{%- extends 'full.tpl' -%}

{% block input_group %}
    {%- if cell.metadata.get('nbconvert', {}).get('show_code', False) -%}
        ((( super() )))
    {%- endif -%}
{% endblock input_group %}
```

Then convert your notebook to HTML with:

`jupyter nbconvert --to html --template hidecode YourNotebook.ipynb`

Comment: I have tried it and put on some analysis notebooks for production. It works just beautifuly! :-)

Comment: tpl code looks like magic. Where is the best resource to learn html/pdf templates for nbconvert?

Comment: I mean `{% tomato`  vs `{%- tomato`. And `((( )))`, seriously, are you trying to impress lisp? XD

Answer (score 16):

In recent versions of `jupyter nbconvert` you can use the `--no-input` option:

````
echo 'A Markdown cell with an equation $x=y+1$

```python
1 + 1
```
' | jupytext --to ipynb | jupyter nbconvert --stdin --execute --no-input --to html --output notebook.html
````

Now if you don't have the `--no-input` option, use `--TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True`, which is available from version 5.2.1 on.

Answer (score 12):

Complementing @vincentVega answer, you need to add the `--to` statement, otherwise it will throw the following error: `ValueError: Please specify an output format with '--to <format>'.`

```
jupyter nbconvert YourNotebook.ipynb --no-input --to html
```

Answer (score 10):

Have your jupyter notbook ready
Go to Anaconda Prompt -> location of the jupyter notebook and enter the below command

```
jupyter nbconvert yourNotebook.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt
```

This will convert the Jupyter notebook to html with all the cells aligned to right.

Comment: I have tried and it creates an html file but empty, without content. What can be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

For my use case I wanted to be able to create export without outputs from within a notebook, and with as little manual work as possible. An adequate solution I managed to glue together is as follows:

In first cell execute some javascript to get the name of the current notebook. The name will be stored in the `nb_name` variable which accessible within current python runtime scope.

Cell 1:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"')
```

In cell 2 pass the obtained name to a shell call and store a html with `--no-input`. The "!" in a jupyter notebook indicates a shell call and "&" is used to pass a variable from current python runtime scope to the shell call.

Cell 2:

```
print(nb_name)
!jupyter nbconvert --output-dir='./docs' --no-input --to html $nb_name
```

Comment: I am trying to test these statements that you indicate, and the first one returns the following error. " Javascript Error: illegal character U+0040". What can be the cause?

Comment: No idea, perhaps it is a system issue. What OS are you using? 
Also the  unicode character U+0040  is suppose to be “@”  and
there is no "@" in my lines.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion of ipynb code file to a HTML file without code(Using Python)::

Step1: Suppose your file Untitled.ipynb is saved in your laptop's Downloads folder.

Step2: Open Anaconda prompt or Cmd , Paste the below command to hide the codes and save the file as Untitled.html:

- cd Downloads
- jupyter nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --to=html --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True

Note: path to the Untitled.ipynb could be different and needs to be changed where we are using cd Downloads to cd new_path.

Answer (score 0):

I used nbinteract (https://www.nbinteract.com/) to publish the page and #HIDDEN (https://gitter.im/nbinteract/Lobby/) on top of the cell. It is undocumented and bound to change, but they'll keep it for backwards compatibility..

Answer (score 0):

For others that might want to hide a specific code cell, one solution is to use a command line tool in `nbdev` package (developed by fastai) to export jupyter notebooks to markdown. The command is `nbdev_nb2md`.

When you do this, if you put `#hide` at the top of any notebook cell, it won't be exported to markdown. It will be ignored.

See this blog post for full details: https://www.fast.ai/2020/01/20/nb2md/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users run this command in PowerShell

```
python -m nbconvert --to html --no-input your_notebook.ipynb
```