# Vscode .net interactive notebooks hide code when exporting to HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-interactive, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

How do I hide the code cell when exporting .net interactive notebooks in visual studio code?

For instance,
[image]

I'd like to export the output, which is the `latex` display part [image] of the example above,

while excluding the actual code cell [image] from being exported.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907455/hide-code-when-exporting-jupyter-notebook-to-html) for Jupyter notebook but I can't seem to make it work for vscode.

My best option, for now, is to export the whole file to HTML and then manually exclude the elements that are not needed.