# How to obtain a shrink-wrapped Jupyter document?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am very new to Jupyter Notebook so I might have missed the obvious, please point me in the right direction (it may also be JN is not the right tool for the task).

I am preparing a piece of documentation which is composed by Some narrative text (in Markdown format) interspersed with images produced using various tools.

I have a tentative Notebook showing what I need.

I can also export in PDF format either from command line or from menu.

Problem is the exported pages include both "cell content" and actual output, together with all `In [xx]` and `Out [yy]` flags and everything Jupyter finds fit to add (e.g.: warnings), while I would like to have "shrink wrapped" documentation containing only the "Out" parts, without any "decoration".

I assume it should be possible, but I couldn't find out how.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524517/8508004) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/generating-reports-for-jupyter-notebooks/279/22). Or [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-output-both-notebook-with-output-cell-and-html-without-running-twice/4749/2?u=fomightez) and combine it with saving as PDF instead of HTML, like second code block shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029786/8508004). You run those types of code in a terminal with a working directory where the notebook file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some comments if you did want to use the notebooks you have and just not have the input code cells show up and still get a pdf the traditional way.

I think though in regards to your statement, "it may also be JN is not the right tool for the task":

That may or may not be the case.
**However, I'd suggest you may want to add additional tools to your toolbox that handle the steps in conjunction with the notebooks.**
You may want to incorporate  [MyST-tools](https://myst-tools.org/) / [JupyterBooks](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/intro.html) or [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) into your flow for 'shrink-wrapping'.

For some current stuff on MyST ([MyST-tools](https://myst-tools.org/)), see:

- ["Inline variables & sliders &  @matplotlib sparklines & task-lists that work. In #jupyter, with @myst_tools
  ."](https://twitter.com/rowancockett/status/1656157176807964675)
- ["Awesome and entertaining talk from @franklinwkoch  if you use notebooks and publish, definitely one to watch on the @JupyterCon video catch ups"](https://twitter.com/stevejpurves/status/1656230651677364224)
- ["Come learn about all the new things in @myst_tools at #JupyterCon2023: One talk on MyST & one on Thebe. Add Jupyter to any web page, click a button and make your graphs live! . Now also works with JupyterLite Computations directly in your web browser."](https://twitter.com/myst_tools/status/1656153512081002497)
- [" 3min demo of the revolutionary new #MySTMarkdown for writing scientific articles" from JupyterCon 20023](https://twitter.com/myst_tools/status/1659233262659596289)

Some current stuff on Quarto:

- slides for 'Publishing Jupyter Notebooks with Quarto' at JupyterCon 2023 are [here](https://jjallaire.quarto.pub/jupytercon-2023/#/title-slide)